How do I increment the value of a 7 segment display by 2
I want to increment the value of the 7 segment display by 2 or 3 for each clock pulse. How do I construct the logic circuit for this without using a microcontroller or an Arduino Uno/Mega.

Only even values? Or only odd values? Do you want to exceed a decimal digit? Or wrap around before getting into non-BCD values?

You will not be incrementing a symbol on a bunch of LEDs, but the value/number/bitpattern that gets encoded into a 7-segment symbol.
So basically, just add two to the value, in whatever form you store it. Bits in binary is a good assumption.
Which is same as increasing a binary value twice by one. Which means leaving the least significant bit untouched and adding one to the second least significant bit.

Here's how you could do it for counting by 2. Counting by 3 is going to be a bit trickier.
In binary multiplying by 2 is the same as shifting the bits by 1, so you could use a binary counter chip and a BCD to 7 Segment decoder and hook it up with the bits offset.
For example, something like this would take three bits from a counter and shift them up, so
0000 = 0 becomes 0000 = 0
0001 = 1 becomes 0010 = 2
0010 = 2 becomes 0100 = 4
0011 = 3 becomes 0110 = 6
0100 = 4 becomes 1000 = 8
and so on up to
0111 = 7 becomes 1110 = 14

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Of course a single digit isn't going to display 14, it will give some symbol representing 14 depending on the decoder used. You could add a second decoder and digit which would take a bit more design work. For a 4 bit counter, once it reaches 7 the first 3 bits will repeat, so you'll get the same output for 8 to 15 as you did for 0 to 7 which actually makes things easier.

The OP wants to add 2 (or 3), not multiply.

@brhans: I believe the point is that if you multiple the counter value by two, every increment of the counter adds two to the displayed value.

@brhans Well, it's multiplying counts by 2, so the result is the same as adding 2.
